# Largest antisymmetric relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hello I'm a student and I'm trying to do this exercise, but I'm stuck. I can't understand why there shouldn't be a largest antisymmetric relation on A... any ideas? The textbook from which the exercise is taken is "How to prove it" by Prof. Velleman, Section 4.4,num 28:

Suppose A is a set:
Prove that if A has at least two elements then there is no largest antisymmetric relation on A

Proof:

Suppose A has at least two elements, then:
$$\neg\exists R\subseteq A*A(\forall S \subseteq A*A(S\subseteq R))\space iff\space\forall R \subseteq A*A(\exists S \subseteq A*A(S \nsubseteq R))$$
So we should find a relation on A*A such that S is "bigger" than R and also antysimmetric.

Let S be the relation defined by:
$$S=R\space\cup\space\{\{R\}\}$$
Then, S is "bigger" than R. S is also antisymmetric.

Is this proof correct? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Here are a very big hint for (1) and a smaller hint for (2).

1. Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are distinct elements of $A$. The relation $R_1=\{\langle a,b\rangle\}$ is an antisymmetric relation on $A$, and so is the relation $R_2=\{\langle b,a\rangle\}$. If $R$ is the largest antisymmetric relation on $A$, then (by the definition of *largest* in this context) $R_1\subseteq R$ and $R_2\subseteq R$. But in that case can $R$ actually be antisymmetric?
2. Because $R$ is a total order, we know that for all $a,b\in A$ with $a\ne b$, exactly one of $a\,R\,b$ and $b\,R\,a$ already holds. If we add any new ordered pair to $R$ to make a strictly bigger relation, ...